Heavy DB operations in sockets.io for millions of users
I am working on a chat app and front end is in Flutter and socket.io which is implemented in Node JS. Now I want to make an event in socket for send_message which will actually an "on" event.
When back-end receives this event then it will first emit the message to receiver and then add the message in DB.
Now I have a concern as message storage is compulsory so is it feasible to perform DB transaction like add, update and read in the event body? Like what if sockets connections gets larger in numbers and so the DB calls and DB data also. What potential challenges I might face if I asked back-end to handle DB in sockets.
My DB is Mongoose DB and sockets are sockets.io

 socket.on("send_message", (message) => {
            socket.in(to_id).emit("message", message)
            await response = db.add("messages",message)// this is a rough query
    });


I'd recommend to only worry about this once you have millions of concurrent users. Chances are you'll need more rearchitecturing at that point anyway.

@AKX thankyou. So it means at that point I have to reconsider that architecture? then this means it would increase the cost of development? Would it work for users in thousands?

Cost of development, cost of hosting, etc., yes. "Would it work" is a nebulous question - depends on your requirements for latency upper bounds, connection errors, etc, etc. The only way to know for sure is to test and benchmark your solution with e.g. a thousand concurrent (simulated) users.
